# Get User Unique Identifier - iOS + Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

What is the proper way to get the user info? This is the flow with Cognito Auth:

User signs in -> Lambda post confirmation creates a 1:1 user in Dynamo using email as unique identifier.

How do I get the Unique identifier of the current signed in user? I'm getting a weird id if I do: `Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser()` I get something like:

```
Optional(AmplifyPlugins.AWSAuthUser(username: "201cdc94-48cc-48a9-9393-9025f13b6fb3", userId: "201cdc94-48cc-48a9-9393-9025f13b6fb3"))
```

When I try:

```
Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes() { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let attributes):
        print("User attributes - \(attributes)")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Fetching user attributes failed with error \(error)")
    }
}
```

I see the email there, how do I get that email? I tried `attributes.email` and doesn't work

What is the correct way to get the Unique Identifier of the current user signed in?

EDIT: Below is a variant I came up with but I feel it's wrong, it can't be this hard... any ideas?

```
func fetchAttributes() -> String {
    var userId:String = ""
    
    Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes() { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let attributes):
            for x in attributes {
                if x.key.rawValue == "email" {
                    print(x.value)
                    userId = x.value
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Fetching user attributes failed with error \(error)")
        }
    }
    return userId
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual the Amplify Support is null... I ended up figuring it out on my own. So it seems Amplify doesn't provide the Unique Identifier for security reasons.

> An intentional decision with Amplify Auth was to avoid any public
> methods exposing credentials or manipulating them.

So I decided to instead of creating the DynamoDB with the Unique Identifier to create it with the Sub Id which can be fetched like:

```
let usersub = try identityProvider.getUserSub().get()
```

More [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/access_credentials/q/platform/ios)